# Does Sql Server 2008 support Database Sharding

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Does Microsoft support implementing Database Sharding using Sql Server 2008 R2 (any edition). From my limited understanding of it, I think, we could probably implement it using Sql Server Express. But I was not sure if Microsoft supports it or not.

[Database Sharding Resource Link](http://www.codefutures.com/database-sharding/)

Other than Distributed Partitioned Views, Data-Dependent Routing, what other options are available for Scale-out? (Peer-to-Peer Transactional Replication, Federated DB?)

Please share any URL that describe any implementation architectures in detail.

Thanks,
_UB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

+1 to gbn. It's worth mentioning that SQL Azure does support sharding (federations) if you were considering other options.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1926.how-to-shard-with-sql-azure.aspx

Answer (score 6):

No, SQL Server doesn't support sharding. SQL Server scales *up* not *out*.

This applies to RDBMS in general:

- [CAP theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem) says you can have at most 2 of C, A and P.
- RDBMS are [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) compliant which is the point of using them

The "C" in both acronyms is "Consistency" and sharding sacrifices "Consistency"
So generally sharding and consistency are mutually exclusive

There are exceptions (more or less) of course. Some examples:

- Oracle RAC which is expensive and tricky
- MySQL replication which is [**not** Consistent](http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtradb-cluster/intro.html)
- MySQL cluster [sacrifices Availability in case of node failure](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-cluster-evaluation-guide/), and can be set to prioritize either [consistency or availability](http://messagepassing.blogspot.ro/2012/03/cap-theorem-and-mysql-cluster.html)

Comment: Thank you. From what I know, there are some options available to scale out with Sql Server. I can't recollect the details, but it is possible.     In database Sharding, `Consistency` is not **impossible**. There is lot of architectural planning that is needed though. I have not heard of CAP theorem, but I will read the article.

Comment: I didn't say not impossible, but it isn't generally done. For scale out, see http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7454/630

Comment: Thank you, it is useful. Though the answer is not what I would like to see, it is what it is.

Comment: Scaling Out SQL Server : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479364.aspx

Comment: @clickstefan: none of those are real "scaling out" in the sense of "add more nodes"

Comment: @gbn probably :), but I thought it's worth to have it here for reference, so people know their official solution for "scaling out".

Comment: I see that according to the official documentation, [MySQL Cluster Evaluation guide](http://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/white-papers/mysql-cluster-evaluation-guide/): "In terms of CAP, MySQL Cluster will [sacrifice availability](http://messagepassing.blogspot.co.uk/2012/03/cap-theorem-and-mysql-cluster.html) to maintain consistency in the event of an unsurvivable network partition."

Comment: @clickstefan: which is what SQL Server/Oracle.PG/Sybase do too

Comment: so Mysql cluster doesn't have either **C** or **A** from **CAP**?